# Python list not getting passed?

Tags: python, list, tuples, unique

```
def main():

    winners = []
    winnersND = []

    readData()
    noDuplicates(winners)


def readData():

    winners_file = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r')

    winners = winners_file.readlines()

    winners_file.close()

    index = 0
    while index < len(winners):
            winners[index] = winners[index].rstrip('\n')
            index += 1

    print(winners)
    print()
    print()

    return winners


def noDuplicates(winners):

    winnersND = []

    for x in winners:
            if x not in winnersND:
                    winnersND.append(x)

    print (winnersND)

    winnersND = tuple(winnersND)

    return winnersND

main()
```

So I've been looking everywhere and I've gone through seven hours worth of iterations of code trying to make this work, but for some reason, the winners list gets printed in `readData()`, but the `winnersND` list, a list of unique and ordered winners list elements, does NOT get printed, and instead displays the output: `[]` . I'd love to get some clarification on what I'm messing up here. Thank you!

Comment: You can downvote a post that's asking for help? How does that make sense XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
winners = readData() # you need to return the list here...
noDuplicates(winners) # otherwise it's empty here.
```

This could all be done like this.

```
def main():
    winners = [x.rstrip() for x in open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt').readlines()]
    winnersND = list(set(winners))
```

Since you asked in the comments, this is how you can check how many times each team has won.

```
from collections import Counter
for winner, count in Counter(winners).iteritems():
    print '{0} has won {1} times'.format(winner, count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I went ahead and tried running what you wrote after "This could all be done like this" as well, however, if I just try to print winners in the main, the entire list is displayed, not an ordered list of the unique elements.

Comment: The unique elements are in `winnersND`. You don't have any sorting in your initial code, so I don't know how you intend to sort it.

Comment: Just saw your edit from the first post, it works beautifully, thank you so much :) do you know what the easiest way for me to put a count for how many of each unique element show up in the winners list, to the left of the winnersND list elements is?

Answer (score 0):

Because `winners` is `main` is an empty list. You reassign a variable called `winners` in `readData()` and return it, but you don't capture the return value. So `main` goes on to pass an empty `winners` list to `noDuplicates()`.

Try changing `main` to:

```
def main():
    winners = readData()
    winnersND = noDuplicates(winners)
```

Comment: So I did exactly this, and it worked! Thank you :) but now, I'm getting two prints of both the winners and winnersND lists. Why is that?

Comment: Depends what your code says. Sounds like maybe you left in some of what was there before in `main` instead of replacing it with the stuff I posted.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
print winners
```

in `noDuplicates()` function, 
it is a blank list that's why you are getting a blank list, because getting the data from blank list.

You trying to access `winners` that you assign in `main()` but changes it in `readData()` function, when you try to access `winners` outside that function it will show a blank list.

Try this:-

```
def noDuplicates(winners):  
    winnersND = []
    for x in readData(): #  use readData() instead winners
        if x not in winnersND:
            winnersND.append(x)

    print (winnersND)   
    winnersND = tuple(winnersND)
    return winnersND
```

or store `readData()` return value in a variable so that:-

```
data = readData()
```

and then apply `for` loop

```
for x in data:
   .
   .
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I tried this, but it hasn't worked yet :( I'm fiddling around with it.

Comment: @Zach it's working fine for me, you should try again and show error if there is any.

Comment: @down voter please tell me my mistake in that approach i will appreciate and try to give answer accordingly.